# Python 2.7 logging format is ignored in production environment only

Tags: python-2.7, logging

my init code is as followed

```
# app.py

fmt = "%(asctime)s - %(request_id)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
logging.basicConfig(format=fmt, level=logging.INFO)

# user controller.py
import logging
logging.info("info success getting profile for user_id " + str(id))
```

It works in `dev` and `staging` and it even worked in `production`. It stopped 2 months ago. Since then I've suspected config, so I've hard coded the log_level - which worked at some extent. it's logging the messages now, just **not in the same format** as other environments

For example a log message in `staging`

```
2018-03-08 07:32:24,661 - API_USER_23a75d85c1a0 - root - ERROR - success getting profile for user_id 1111
```

But in `production` The same message will be:

```
ERROR:root:success getting profile for user_id 1111
```

What Can i do to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, `logging.basicConfig` does NOT take effect if there are root logger handlers already configured which happens if you log before. That sucks. Should be a big fat sign that screams, “your init didn’t take effect!!”

My solution was making sure `root.handlers` are empty before calling `basicConfig`

```
root = logging.getLogger()
if root.handlers:
    root.error('haha , that\'s why the basicConfig didn\'t take effect!!')
    for handler in root.handlers:
        root.removeHandler(handler)

logging.basicConfig(format=fmt, level=self.app.config.get('LOG_LEVEL'))
```